# permission denied in sites-available

Tags: permissions, apache2, lamp

I am new to ubuntu.I install LAMP pakage acording to this page.
I want to create new website such as say in this article.
but when I create my site in "sites-avalible" and whant to chanege it and save,show a message ...

```
Error opening file '/etc/apache2/sites-available/mysite': Permission denied

The file on disk may now be truncated!
```

what I should to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to run your editor with `sudo`, because site configuration files cannot be modified by users.

For example:

```
$ ls -l /etc/apache2/sites-available/default
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  950 2011-06-07 14:56 default
```

You should try to follow the official [Ubuntu Server Guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/11.10/serverguide/C/httpd.html). It is a very concise and clearly written article on what you'd like to achive.

Answer (score 1):

To fix it, use sudo to edit the file:
`sudo -H gedit /etc/apache2/sites-available/default` 
Then enter your password, and that's it.

`gedit` is one possible editor, but you can use any of them you like:  vim, nano, pico, etc..